# How do I make Mulitbit show the exchange rate?

Tags: multibit, exchange-rate

I recently started using Multibit and today when I opened it the app wouldn't load exchange rates on any of my wallets.

[image: Multibit exchange rate]

It shows my balance but not the value in dollars. I have it set to do so but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Bitstamp is currently offline for security reasons so that will be why. It'll be back within a day or two. Perhaps there's an option to switch it to use a different exchange's rates.. if not, there should be.

Comment: There is. http://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_ticker.html

Answer (score 0):

Bitstamp is currently offline. Here's how to get prices from somewhere else:

1. Click on the currency ticker.

   [image: Currency ticker, click to configure]
2. This will open the preferences menu.

   Scroll down and click the drop down menu labelled "Exchange"

   [image: preference menu, scroll down to exchange]
3. Click "Apply changes"

   [image: apply changes]
4. Done!

   [image: new prices displayed]